How I can re render the cells of my react-table tanstack with conditional defaultColumn
I want from the following code to show the defaultColumn (which will stop editing data as an input) conditionally based on a toggle button that will change the state of isEditable
The problem is that even when the state of isEditable changes it does not render again the table therefore does not change the component of the table cells
component containing the table:
import { 
  useEffect, 
  useState 
} from 'react'

import { 
  InputFilterColumn, 
  PaginationContainer, 
  SelectFilterColumn, 
  TableContainer 
} from './styled'
import { 
  ArrowDownward, 
  ArrowUpward 
} from '@mui/icons-material'

import { 
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel, 
  getFilteredRowModel, 
  getPaginationRowModel, 
  getSortedRowModel, 
  useReactTable 
} from '@tanstack/react-table'

const defaultColumn = {
  cell: ({getValue, row: { index }, column: { id }, table}) => {

    const initialValue = getValue()

    return(
      <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{ initialValue }</p>
    )
  }
}

export const Table = ({ 
  tableData=[],
  globalFilter,
  setGlobalFilter,
  defaultColumns,
  isEditable: editableInitialValue
}) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([...defaultColumns])

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(tableData)
  }, [tableData])

  useEffect(() => {
    setColumns([...defaultColumns])
  }, [defaultColumns])

  // sorting
  const [sorting, setSorting] = useState([])

  // pagination
  const [pagination, setPagination] = useState({
    pageIndex: 0,
    pageSize: 12
  })

  // column filtering
  const [columnFilters, setColumnFilters] = useState([])

  // editable data
  const [isEditable, setIsEditable] = useState(editableInitialValue)

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsEditable(editableInitialValue)
    setColumnFilters([])
  }, [editableInitialValue])

  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    defaultColumn: isEditable ? defaultColumn : undefined,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
    state: {
      sorting,
      globalFilter,
      pagination,
      columnFilters
    },
    onSortingChange: setSorting,
    onGlobalFilterChange: setGlobalFilter,
    onPaginationChange: setPagination,
    onColumnFiltersChange: setColumnFilters
  })

  return (
    <TableContainer>
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            {table.getHeaderGroups().map(headerGroup => (
              <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map(header => (
                  <th key={header.id}
                    style={{
                      width: header.getSize()
                    }}
                  >
                    <div
                      onClick={header.column.getToggleSortingHandler()}
                    >
                      {header.isPlaceholder
                        ? null: flexRender(
                          header.column.columnDef.header,
                          header.getContext()
                        )}
                        {
                          {'asc': <ArrowUpward />, 'desc': <ArrowDownward /> }[
                            header.column.getIsSorted() ?? null
                          ]
                        }
                    </div>
                    <Filter column={header.column}/>
                  </th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {table.getRowModel().rows.map(row => (
              <tr key={row.id}>
                {row.getVisibleCells().map(cell => (
                  <td key={cell.id}
                    style={{
                      width: cell.column.getSize()
                    }}
                  >
                    {flexRender(
                      cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                      cell.getContext()
                    )}
                  </td>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>  
      <PaginationContainer>
        <div>
          <button
            onClick={() => table.firstPage()}
            disabled={!table.getCanPreviousPage()}
          >
            {'<<'}
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={() => table.previousPage()}
            disabled={!table.getCanPreviousPage()}
          >
            {'<'}
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={() => table.nextPage()}
            disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}
          >
            {'>'}
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={() => table.lastPage()}
            disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}
          >
            {'>>'}
          </button>
        </div>
        <span>
          Página 
          <strong>
            {' '} {table.getState().pagination.pageIndex + 1} de {' '}
            {table.getPageCount()}
          </strong>
        </span>
        <select
          value={table.getState().pagination.pageSize}
          onChange={(e) => {
            table.setPageSize(Number(e.target.value))
          }}
        >
          {[12,20,30,50,80].map(pageSize => (
            <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
              Mostrar {pageSize}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </PaginationContainer>
    </TableContainer>
  )
}

const Filter = ({ column }) => {

  const columnFilterValue = column.getFilterValue()
  const { filterVariant, options } = column.columnDef.meta ?? {}

  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState((columnFilterValue ?? ''))

  return filterVariant === 'select' 
    ? (
      <SelectFilterColumn
        onChange={({target}) => {
          setInputValue(target.value)
          column.setFilterValue(target.value)
        }}
        value={ inputValue }
      >
        {
          options.map((option, i) => (
            <option key={i} value={ option === 'Todo' ? '' : option }>
              { option }
            </option>
          ))
        }
      </SelectFilterColumn>
    )
    : (
      <InputFilterColumn
        type="text"
        onChange={({target}) => {
          setInputValue(target.value)
          column.setFilterValue(target.value)
        }}
        value={inputValue}
      />
    )
}

parent component:
import { 
  useEffect, 
  useState 
} from 'react'

import { TableContainer } from './styled'
import { Table, TitleActionBar } from '../../components/CMDBEmails'

import { emailsDataRequest } from './emailsDataRequest'

export const CMDBEmails = () => {

  const [areasData, setAreasData] = useState([])
  const [registersData, setRegistersData] = useState([])

  const { 
    getAreasData, 
    getRegistersData
  } = emailsDataRequest(setAreasData, setRegistersData)

  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')
 
  useEffect(() => {
    getAreasData()
    getRegistersData()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    setDefaultColumns(prevColumns => prevColumns.map(column => 
      (column.meta && column.meta.filterVariant === 'select')
      ? {...column, meta: {...column.meta, options: ['Todo', ...areasData.map(({area}) => area)]}}
      : column
    ))
  }, [areasData])

  const [defaultColumns, setDefaultColumns] = useState([
    {
      header: 'Nombre',
      accessorKey: 'name',
      size: 340
    },
    {
      header: 'Correo',
      accessorKey: 'email',
      size: 340
    },
    {
      header: 'Contraseña',
      accessorKey: 'password',
      size: 240
    },
    {
      header: 'Área',
      accessorKey: 'area',
      size: 300,
      meta: {
        filterVariant: 'select',
        options: []
      }
    }
  ])

  const [isEditable, setIsEditable] = useState(false)

  return (
    <>
      <TitleActionBar 
        setIsEditable={ setIsEditable }
      />
      <TableContainer>
        <Table
          tableData={ registersData }
          defaultColumns={ defaultColumns }
          globalFilter={ inputValue }
          setGlobalFilter={ setInputValue }
          isEditable={ isEditable }
        />
      </TableContainer>
    </>
  )
}

component that contains the toggle button:
import { ActionButton } from '../../../../components'
import { 
  ActionBar, 
  Container 
} from './styled'

export const TitleActionBar = ({
  setIsEditable
}) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <h2>CMDB Correos</h2>
      <ActionBar>
        <ActionButton 
          text="Editar"
          padding="5px 10px"
          action={() => setIsEditable(value => !value)}
        />
      </ActionBar>
    </Container>
  )
}

I hope that when I press the toggle button, depending on its value, the component that is inside defaultColumn will be displayed
